# Default Slicers to Users using Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am currently an expert Power BI desktop user and I have been asked by my organisation to default slicers back to the specific user.

I have originally tried using Row Level Security (RLS) to allow the slicers to default to the user but can understand that this locks that single row of data out specifically to the user.

The user needs to be able to compare their data against other users in the dashboard.

Is there a way I can resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Not currently possible to set slicer based on a measure with the default slicers available.

You may want to try [Preselected Slicer](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/insiderscoop1611244107840.powerbi_customviz_preselected-slicer?tab=Overview) - a custom visual available in AppSource.